# Searching by inner text with HTML datalist

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, html-datalist

I am using a simple HTML5 datalist which serves as an autocomplete dropdownlist on a Chrome browser. The datalist I use is something like this:

```
<datalist id="mylist">
    <option value="123">Oranges</option>
     <option value="2312">Apples</option>
     <option value="33232">Bananas</option>
</datalist>
```

here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/internetbird/EQZud/):

The problem is that when I start to type a value the search is done on the **value** instead on the text. Also the value is displayed to the user.

Basically, what I want to do is:

1) Search by inner text

2) Display only the inner text when the user views the dropdownlist's options.

I did a few Google searches, but could not find an answer to this very simple task...

Comment: I'm kinda confused as to what you would want to happen...when you select an option, it populates an `<input type="text" />`. Whatever the `value` of the text input is, that's what is displayed to the user, and that's also the value that gets submitted. Are you looking to have `Oranges` displayed in the text input when chosen, but `123` submitted? I don't believe you can do this with a text input. Or are you looking to have `Oranges` displayed and submitted? If that's the case, just remove the `value` attribute from your `<option>` elements altogether.

Comment: If you want `Oranges` displayed in the text input and `123` submitted, the only way I can think to do that would be to use JavaScript to change the value when the form is submitted. In this case you can just swap your inner text and your value...it doesn't really matter which one is which, since you'll be changing it on submit anyways.

Comment: The problem is that other project depends on the value field, but I guess I will need to change this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into `typeahead.js`. You can read up on it [here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/). It's an extremely useful library for this kind of thing.

Looking at the website, all you would have to do is the following:

```
var options = ["Oranges", "Apples", "Bananas"];

$('#yourDropDownElement .typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
},
{
    name: 'fruit',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: substringMatcher(options)
});
```

This does require jQuery, however.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , but I would be happy if I could achive the result without using any additional libraries

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just replace value by your inner text?
something like:

```
<input type="text" list="mylist">
<datalist id="mylist">
    <option value="Oranges" value2="123"></option>
     <option value="Apples" value2="2312"></option>
     <option value="Bananas" value2="33232"></option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: I can't replace them because I already has a code which is dependent on the value field

Answer (score 0):

1) Please define your options like that:

```
<option value="123" label="Oranges"/>
```

2) Depends on a browser: Firefox doesn't show values, while Chrome shows them as an additional info.

Comment: Given that search will still be by value if you do this it does not answer the question.