# Search HTML5 Datalist by Value and inner text (or some other property)

Tags: html

I am attempting to find a way so that when a user enters text into the data list, they can come across the same entry by course number (E.G. "CS 101") or course name (E.G. "Intro to Computer Science).

Currently, what I have is only searchable by the value field:

```
    <datalist id="tagList">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="CSCI 4950">Senior Software Project</option>
      <option value="CSCI 5117">Developing the Interactive Web</option>
      <option value="CSCI 5421">Advanced Algorithms</option>
      <option value="CSCI 5980">Design Methods for Comp. Sci.</option>
    </datalist>
```

1. The solution needs to work in the Android Webkit web browser (Phonegap) -- Chrome seems to handle Datalists the same as Android's native browser so if it works in Chrome I should be ok.
2. It needs to display both the course name and course number to the user
3. This needs to be generalizable and not hard-coded as I am using AngularJS to actually populate the full list of courses.

---

**What I've tried**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22827978/2831961 -- For some reason, this didn't work.

I've also tried a similar strategy, but with the data-value attribute. That didn't work either. Unless I am responsible for some behind the scenes Javascript work that I am unaware of.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rh48cgrj/3/

Here's a fiddle. I put the option values/text into key:value pairs in a javascript object. NOTE: **the key** is an index number and **the value** is the option value attribute AND the text. This makes it easier to search them for our text.

```
var i = 0;
var selectItems = {}
$('#tagList option').each(function() {
var listvalue = $(this).val();
var listtext = $(this).text();
selectItems[i] = listvalue + " " + listtext + ",";
i++;
});
```

Then I split them into rows that included both value and text.

```
count = i;
for(i=0; i < count;i++) {
var blockoftext = blockoftext + " " + selectItems[i].toLowerCase() + ",";
}
```

I then setup a search function that would search those rows to see if any returned a match, and if they did the result was outputted to a div below the search box.

```
var texttosplit = blockoftext.split(",");

var searchresults;

     for(i=0; i < texttosplit.length; i++) {
    (texttosplit[i].indexOf(searchvalue.toLowerCase()) != -1) ?
    (searchresults = texttosplit[i] + "<br>") : false;
    $("#searched").html(searchresults);
}
```

There's an example for all of the above in the fiddle.

EDIT: The below is the commented code for the loop to check if search text is in the datalist per op request.

```
    for (i = 0; i < texttosplit.length; i++) {  
//The above loops through our array of class values and titles

    (texttosplit[i].indexOf(searchvalue.toLowerCase()) != -1) ? 
// The above determines if our search text is in class title using a ternary operator
// our array of class values and titles is lowercase so we make 
//sure our search text is lowercase as well
// if we find a match between the search text and the class title/values perform the following:

    (searchresults = texttosplit[i].replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
    })
// The above replaces the first char of every word with an uppercase char
    .replace("Csci", "CSCI") + "<br>", 
// The above finds Csci and changes it to CSCI since all THOSE letters should be uppercase

    prevtext = $("#searched").html(),
//get current text of element with id "searched" and place it in prevtext
    $("#searched").html(prevtext + searchresults)) 
//append "searched" by adding it's current text with the new searchresults

    : 
//if search text is not in the class title return false
    false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! However, 2 questions. 1) Is it possible for this to show up in the <datalist> element instead of a separate textbox? 2) I didn't look closely at the code but why does the search only return the last occurence that is similar. For example, searching just 5 returns the only last element. Otherwise, if this is not possible, I might decide to just do 2 separate datalists where one is searchable by number and the other by name.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf09ydu7/7/ I cleaned up the code a bit. Only showing the last element when you searched was an error on my part, instead of appending to the search results div I overwrote it, so I fixed that for you. Also I fixed the code so that when you return a search result all the words begin with an uppercase char.

Comment: @BlazeBiker Do you have any other questions on this subject? :D 
Otherwise, if I thoroughly answered your question, please accept it to help others find it on the site!

Comment: With the cleaned up fiddle it makes more sense, but would you mind explaining lines 20-25 in the fiddle to me? I'm new to Javascript. I see that if the search string is a substring of text to search, you replaced all letters with uppercase ones??? and following that I lost where it is going when you added on the second replace() call.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf09ydu7/8/ will show you the commented code! I also edited it onto the answer above. What the code does is:
1. Turn our search text to lowercase to match our array
2. check if the search text is in our array of class titles/values. 
3. If it is then it changes the first character of every word back to upper case using regex /\b[a-z]/g
4. Since CSCI is now Csci we change Csci back to CSCI with a replace command.
5. We store prev search results in prevtext, and append the current search results to element with id "searched"

6. If the search text doesn't match, return false.

Comment: Thanks for being  incredibly thorough. This was easily my best SO experience thusfar! I know SO discourages these kinds of comments, but the effort you took to explain this to me is very appreciated!

Comment: It's no problem, I'm glad I could help!