# HTML5 DataList - Is it possible?

Tags: html, html-datalist

I have an HTML5 `datalist` that contains about 4,000 records and I need to be able to search based on the innerText of the option value.

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
      <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">IE - Worst Browser</option>
    <option value="Firefox">FF - Was cool</option>
    <option value="Chrome">Google - It just works</option>
    </datalist>
```

The goal is that when I search for example Worst I get the options back with that substring. And when they click on the option It gets populated with the value (Which it is already doing for me nicely).

tl;dr is there anyway to set the search possible search terms for each `<option>`

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Data list’s Basic functionality is to enter your own value or to choose from bounded values. In order to manipulate its behavior you should manipulate DOM. 
 This may help!
[Search HTML5 Datalist by Value and inner text (or some other property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477739/search-html5-datalist-by-value-and-inner-text-or-some-other-property)